# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send' for my LED on off code through blynk

Tags: pi-3, python-3, led

I am trying to run a cod for LED on and off through blynk app
but every thime it is showing this error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

my code is

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import blynklib
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(12,GPIO.OUT)
BLYNK_AUTH = 'k6iLZ6jvfsGw3oZaNjCkhUlMUyRd0QT6'
# Initialize Blynk
blynk = blynklib.Blynk(BLYNK_AUTH)
# Register Virtual Pins
#@blynk.virtual_write("readV0")
@blynk.virtual_write(0)
def my_write_handler(value):
        x=(format(value[0]))
        print(x)
        if x=="0":
                print("LED Off")
                GPIO.output(12,0)
        if x=="1":
                print("LED On")
                GPIO.output(12,1)
while True:
        blynk.run()
```

please provide solution for this

Comment: Please post the _entire_ stack trace in code tags so we can debug easier. Thanks :)

Comment: I can not see any relevance to the Raspberry Pi.  This seems to be a problem with blynklib.